# Why is my genetic algorithm seemingly behaving randomly?

Tags: haskell, genetic-algorithm

I'm attempting to evolve optimal strategies for the [Iterated Prisoner's Dilemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prisoner%27s_dilemma#The_iterated_prisoner.27s_dilemma) using a basic genetic algorithm ([Stochastic Universal Sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_universal_sampling), [1-point crossover](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossover_%28genetic_algorithm%29#One-point_crossover), Canonical GA). I've implemented this algorithm in Haskell and recently added chart output. Unfortunately the graphs produced don't fit the expected pattern for this problem so it appears I have a bug.

All graphs of fitnesses I have seen for this problem look something like this:

[image: My friend's graph, looking normal]

Other examples can be seen in [On Evolving Robust Strategies for Iterated Prisoner's Dilemma,  P.J. Darwen and X. Yao (1993) p6-7](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.53.8814&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

However my output looks like this:

[image: My graph looking very strange]

If I set mutation rate to 1 I get:

[image: Flipping between two identical values]

Perhaps suggesting that my selection function is not being quite so random as I had thought as the graph implies a homogeneous population.

My code is in [this git repository](https://bitbucket.org/KitB/nat-coursework/) should you wish to inspect it.

Now for the question: Could any of you suggest what I might be doing wrong in my GA implementation to make the graph look like this?

e.g. I would assume it is unlikely to be the fitness function as I am using the same fitness function for output that it is maximising so even if the fitness function is wrong in some way it will still be maximising that wrong function (though I'm sure I could be wrong here, I'm rather new to genetic algorithms)

I would just like suggestions for which functions to look at, I'm tearing my hair out trying to fix this.

EDIT: Having added some debug code to my combine function it seems that it is always being passed the same individuals (even with mutation set to 1) so presumably selection is going wrong somewhere.

EDIT: Selection was going wrong, but that wasn't causing all the problems, just homogeneity in the population.

Comment: Have you tried [quickcheck](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck)? This seems like the sort of problem where it might be very helpful.

Comment: I've a few quickCheck properties in IteratedPD.hs, it's quite hard to write invariants for nondeterministic functions I find.

Answer (score 3):

You have a function `maybeFlip`, which will change an allele to its opposite with a given probability. Hence, when the mutation rate is 1, you will just keep flipping all the alleles back and forth between two opposites. This explains the zig-zag pattern seen in your graph.

<sub>Also, `swap` is in [`Data.Tuple`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-Tuple.html) :)</sub>

Comment: It explains *a* zig-zag pattern but not zig-zagging between just two values. Due to crossover and selection there should be variation in those two values.

Thanks, I was not aware of swap.

Comment: To elaborate, if I have stochastic selection then there should be some variation in the individuals chosen to enter the next generation. It will only flip between these two average fitnesses if the population is always the same. I've also tried with a few other edge cases and gotten evidence that supports a homogeneous population.

Comment: Hm. I'll try having another look at it later. However, I can give you a testing tip: Try moving as much as possible of the logic into pure functions. For example, your crossover function (although simple) could be implemented in terms of a pure function `crossoverAt` which takes the index to cross over at as an argument. Similarly your `select` could be implemented in terms of a pure function which takes a list of indices. It should be much easier to test your logic that way.